# Hiding section of an appendix in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

Sections in an appendix should look like

```
A.1 Name of the first section
A.2 Name of the second section
```

while in ToC should be only displayed

```
A name of appendix A
```

Using `\section*{Name of the first section}` doesn't work as it affects numbering within an appendix.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\appendix
\chapter{Name of appendix A}
\section*{Name of the first section}
\section{Name of the second section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without any additional package, this can be done by adding the following line just after the `\appendix` command:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} 
\chapter{Name of appendix A}
\section{Name of the first section}
\section{Name of the second section}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: This somehow empties my "List of Figures". How do I fix that?

Comment: @DavidNathan Either use `\protect\value{tocdepth}=0` instead of `\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` or add something like `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` after `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke sorry for this reply. I wonder why `\value{tocdepth}=0` works but `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` doesn't.

Comment: After reading `source2e.pdf`, I found that `\setcounter` makes counter change globally: `\global\csname c@#1\endcsname#2`, and `\value` is local. My question is solved.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`tocvsec2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2) package to change the ToC depth at the desired location:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\appendix
\chapter{Name of appendix A}
\settocdepth{chapter}

\section{Name of the first section}
\section{Name of the second section}

\chapter{Name of appendix B}


\section{Name of the first section}
\section{Name of the second section}
\end{document}
```

[image]